# Como enviar dados de data frames em perguntas sobre código em R otimizado?

Tags: r, data.frame, apply

*Editado - Como apontado no comentário do Marcos Moraes, tentei reinventar a roda de um recurso disponível na camada base do R, uma vez que dput é capaz de produzir o mesmo efeito. Falha nossa. :( A questão central da minha pergunta ainda permanece válida, como otimizar o código abaixo eliminando as estruturas "for"?*

Com frequência ao tentar recorrer ao suporte no stackoverflow é altamente recomendado que enviemos exemplo de códigos e dos dados do problema que estamos enfrentando. 
Enviar o código em geral não acarreta maiores dificuldades, os dados nem sempre.
Há casos onde a geração de sequências e números aleatórios é o suficiente, em outros mais complexos, não.
Resolvi parcialmente esse problema com um código que não adota o estilo compacto e funções da família apply.

Um data frame como o do exemplo abaixo:

[image: Data Frame]
é fornecido à função e retorna uma string com o código correspondente:

```
"df <- data.frame(LONG=c(-37.04821264,-48.48782569,-43.92645317,-60.67053267),LAT=c(-10.9072158,-1.459845,-19.93752429,2.816681919),ALT=c(4.288342,8.471477,937.528005,79.828228),name=c('city1','city2','city3','city4'))"
```

Assim em um único arquivo posso enviar o código e os dados.

A pequena função que desenvolvi:

```
#' dfCode
#' generate a string corresponding to the code
#' of a data frame definition in R
#' 
#' @param df a data frame
#'
#' @return a string with the representation of the data frame
#'         to be used as code in R scripts
#' @export
#'
#' @examples dfCode(df) 
dfCode <- function(df) {

  if(!is.data.frame(df))
  {return(-1)}

  ncols <- ncol(df)
  nrows <- nrow(df)

  k <- "df <- data.frame(" 

  for (j in 1:ncols)
  {
    # open column vector
    k <- paste0(k,colnames(df)[j],"=c(")

    # numeric or not
    for (i in 1:ncols)
    {
      if (is.numeric(df[,j]))
            k <- paste0(k,df[i,j])
      else 
            k <- paste0(k,"'", df[i,j],"'")

      if(i< nrows) # last item no commas
        { k=paste0(k,",")}
    }
    # closing parenthesis vector declaration
    k <- paste0(k,")")

    if(j< ncols)  #last item no commas
    { k=paste0(k,",")}
  }
  k <- paste0(k,")")

  return(k)
}
```

Como seria uma versão no estilo "R", quero dizer compactando os comandos "for" por meio de funções da família "apply"?

Comment: Existe algum motivo específico para usar uma função especial em vez do comando `dput`, já implementado em todas as versões do R?

Comment: @MarcusNunes serei franco, não conhecia a dput :(

Comment: Acontece. Pelo que vejo na internet, `dput` é o comando mais usado para compartilhar dados, [até mesmo aqui no stackoverflow em português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/161610/construindo-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-definindo-x-e-y-usando-r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma proposta:

```
dfCode2 <- function(df) {

  if(!is.data.frame(df))
  {return(-1)}

  k <- "df <- data.frame(" 

  tcs=sapply(colnames(df),function(co) {
    tc=df[,co]
    # open column vector
    ks <- paste0(co,"=c(")

    # numeric or not
      if (is.numeric(tc))
        ks <- paste0(ks,paste0(tc,collapse=","),")")
      else 
        ks <- paste0(ks,"'",paste0(tc,collapse = "','"),"')")
  })
  k <- paste0(k,paste0(tcs,collapse=","),")")

  return(k)
}
```