# Integrando colunas de uma Matriz usando R (Erro)

Tags: r, matemática

Essa é a minha matriz:

```
funcao=structure(c(-14.7690673280818, -14.5543581356252, -12.1406211639974, 
-10.7200919648493, -9.55507848352318, -9.20790894914246, -8.74647670464071, 
-8.26548763467919, -7.3962484443768, -6.94590909664862, -6.63903257406218, 
-6.40598087538929, -6.09621085755895, -5.88245015332806, -5.69615454359131, 
-5.4543516801245, -5.24485270997044, -5.05729667581875, -4.7660441793448, 
-4.39683466679171, -4.30668996362841, -4.0828498417172, -3.95528199743041, 
-3.81741171570944, -3.66175435590196, -3.56271256245504, -3.49609868983868, 
-3.37586125647396, -3.0034966287813, -2.90517151506904, -2.72993249556762, 
-2.66092057836039, -2.4408738658527, -2.36547969703899, -2.09546783234301, 
-1.95526398213212, -1.88470374007828, -1.72750243012653, -1.60575660667247, 
-1.43542615745848, -1.29362975715702, -1.18449733575892, -0.98947894198681, 
-0.853386354928181, -0.63296867063245, -0.527486151545778, -0.361277864998242, 
-0.257665212366851, -0.109270291541468, 0, 0.109270291541468, 
0.257665212366851, 0.361277864998242, 0.527486151545778, 0.63296867063245, 
0.853386354928181, 0.98947894198681, 1.18449733575892, 1.29362975715702, 
1.43542615745848, 1.60575660667247, 1.72750243012653, 1.88470374007828, 
1.95526398213212, 2.09546783234301, 2.36547969703899, 2.4408738658527, 
2.66092057836039, 2.72993249556762, 2.90517151506904, 3.0034966287813, 
3.37586125647396, 3.49609868983868, 3.56271256245504, 3.66175435590196, 
3.81741171570944, 3.95528199743041, 4.0828498417172, 4.30668996362841, 
4.39683466679171, 4.7660441793448, 5.05729667581875, 5.24485270997044, 
5.4543516801245, 5.69615454359131, 5.88245015332806, 6.09621085755895, 
6.40598087538929, 6.63903257406218, 6.94590909664862, 7.3962484443768, 
8.26548763467919, 8.74647670464071, 9.20790894914246, 9.55507848352318, 
10.7200919648493, 12.1406211639974, 14.5543581356252, 14.7690673280818, 
-13.7079821475458, -13.4498703618915, -11.67838231268, -10.4589486406842, 
-8.9432388382521, -8.58312548137122, -8.14102991846389, -7.71079209128989, 
-6.95240042017031, -6.66414427349685, -6.40033205538623, -6.13816822549321, 
-5.77208382991545, -5.49527630669887, -5.33154964830415, -5.12782641892739, 
-4.93206161073643, -4.72556232300793, -4.52080276980657, -4.1694078333758, 
-4.03956026669583, -3.90869860153294, -3.79104380757601, -3.69124767313376, 
-3.47159857371935, -3.3643163654408, -3.29467696235366, -3.16605701449292, 
-2.84435464789616, -2.71650210221017, -2.59690597248341, -2.52388797476942, 
-2.34094207608544, -2.20427426100811, -1.83879580218285, -1.72737794398069, 
-1.6454056454373, -1.5042411957216, -1.38609220687676, -1.2432788707001, 
-1.1225617148797, -1.01318771357089, -0.90038209504245, -0.773284479514442, 
-0.640368323748707, -0.555178375238413, -0.377358821158776, -0.230347860323025, 
-0.110436162251717, 0, 0.110436162251717, 0.230347860323025, 
0.377358821158776, 0.555178375238413, 0.640368323748707, 0.773284479514442, 
0.90038209504245, 1.01318771357089, 1.1225617148797, 1.2432788707001, 
1.38609220687676, 1.5042411957216, 1.6454056454373, 1.72737794398069, 
1.83879580218285, 2.20427426100811, 2.34094207608544, 2.52388797476942, 
2.59690597248341, 2.71650210221017, 2.84435464789616, 3.16605701449292, 
3.29467696235366, 3.3643163654408, 3.47159857371935, 3.69124767313376, 
3.79104380757601, 3.90869860153294, 4.03956026669583, 4.1694078333758, 
4.52080276980657, 4.72556232300793, 4.93206161073643, 5.12782641892739, 
5.33154964830415, 5.49527630669887, 5.77208382991545, 6.13816822549321, 
6.40033205538623, 6.66414427349685, 6.95240042017031, 7.71079209128989, 
8.14102991846389, 8.58312548137122, 8.9432388382521, 10.4589486406842, 
11.67838231268, 13.4498703618915, 13.7079821475458, -14.358609077878, 
-14.1271105147046, -11.9618138886078, -10.6190742201334, -9.31840132054895, 
-8.96622474353695, -8.51227248333579, -8.05091545299969, -7.22455526958365, 
-6.83691436333096, -6.54669635165921, -6.30238324376159, -5.97082920578328, 
-5.73268017960003, -5.55511488901834, -5.32804232266972, -5.12385612117062, 
-4.92897229198519, -4.67117775232928, -4.30885942992513, -4.20335651783943, 
-4.0154831357938, -3.89174994433905, -3.76860783727992, -3.58819663306074, 
-3.48596721027473, -3.41818297549918, -3.29470294456033, -2.94193593581688, 
-2.83218876260999, -2.67847401240583, -2.60791242809822, -2.40221737689215, 
-2.3031208003073, -1.99617971268181, -1.86711111167336, -1.79213635811389, 
-1.64113856670334, -1.52078410227216, -1.36109806339877, -1.22745572081485, 
-1.11822984936273, -0.955013720375685, -0.822400646878094, -0.635831069171161, 
-0.538198299721656, -0.367498441110635, -0.24709807532094, -0.109721283846771, 
0, 0.109721283846771, 0.24709807532094, 0.367498441110635, 0.538198299721656, 
0.635831069171161, 0.822400646878094, 0.955013720375685, 1.11822984936273, 
1.22745572081485, 1.36109806339877, 1.52078410227216, 1.64113856670334, 
1.79213635811389, 1.86711111167336, 1.99617971268181, 2.3031208003073, 
2.40221737689215, 2.60791242809822, 2.67847401240583, 2.83218876260999, 
2.94193593581688, 3.29470294456033, 3.41818297549918, 3.48596721027473, 
3.58819663306074, 3.76860783727992, 3.89174994433905, 4.0154831357938, 
4.20335651783943, 4.30885942992513, 4.67117775232928, 4.92897229198519, 
5.12385612117062, 5.32804232266972, 5.55511488901834, 5.73268017960003, 
5.97082920578328, 6.30238324376159, 6.54669635165921, 6.83691436333096, 
7.22455526958365, 8.05091545299969, 8.51227248333579, 8.96622474353695, 
9.31840132054895, 10.6190742201334, 11.9618138886078, 14.1271105147046, 
14.358609077878, -14.5672256639001, -14.3442603466748, -12.0526932005212, 
-10.6704167793823, -9.43869316924387, -9.08906143604798, -8.63130745231583, 
-8.15997238138419, -7.31181881941087, -6.89231124997616, -6.59362650222709, 
-6.3550370379524, -6.03455479085867, -5.80880119944129, -5.62679869904323, 
-5.39223941682433, -5.1853529853784, -4.99419352909143, -4.7193938866676, 
-4.35357309705323, -4.255876038818, -4.04972245780601, -3.92404029302206, 
-3.79341254883719, -3.62558255722496, -3.52497325621722, -3.4577838613747, 
-3.33595188997765, -2.97322433504632, -2.86928245642403, -2.70462793445213, 
-2.63485397290467, -2.42186464857093, -2.33481488889686, -2.04664318502277, 
-1.91191506158551, -1.8391839961936, -1.68503324864501, -1.56397162198931, 
-1.39887553095015, -1.26108886508264, -1.15191048988921, -0.972530768371285, 
-0.838149222100249, -0.634376246882453, -0.532753819606308, -0.364336815412981, 
-0.252468853112474, -0.109492065710681, 0, 0.109492065710681, 
0.252468853112474, 0.364336815412981, 0.532753819606308, 0.634376246882453, 
0.838149222100249, 0.972530768371285, 1.15191048988921, 1.26108886508264, 
1.39887553095015, 1.56397162198931, 1.68503324864501, 1.8391839961936, 
1.91191506158551, 2.04664318502277, 2.33481488889686, 2.42186464857093, 
2.63485397290467, 2.70462793445213, 2.86928245642403, 2.97322433504632, 
3.33595188997765, 3.4577838613747, 3.52497325621722, 3.62558255722496, 
3.79341254883719, 3.92404029302206, 4.04972245780601, 4.255876038818, 
4.35357309705323, 4.7193938866676, 4.99419352909143, 5.1853529853784, 
5.39223941682433, 5.62679869904323, 5.80880119944129, 6.03455479085867, 
6.3550370379524, 6.59362650222709, 6.89231124997616, 7.31181881941087, 
8.15997238138419, 8.63130745231583, 9.08906143604798, 9.43869316924387, 
10.6704167793823, 12.0526932005212, 14.3442603466748, 14.5672256639001, 
-13.6245844768687, -13.3630613956461, -11.6420519179073, -10.4384236674326, 
-8.89515033208928, -8.53401963497411, -8.0934438691888, -7.66719491633901, 
-6.91751548158816, -6.64199852086489, -6.38157100998465, -6.11711906602055, 
-5.74660855271358, -5.46484576488352, -5.30289294897202, -5.10216264876024, 
-4.90747729878566, -4.69948913603343, -4.50152763272595, -4.15153286112639, 
-4.01856478499323, -3.89501090892983, -3.77813524686729, -3.68133161034538, 
-3.45665297878437, -3.34872310204811, -3.27884590260074, -3.14956711773407, 
-2.83184663180451, -2.70167333082681, -2.5864505421683, -2.51311768021067, 
-2.33308777876224, -2.19160406439047, -1.81862225736669, -1.70946687980764, 
-1.6265976326061, -1.48669362532537, -1.36882733539455, -1.22817675030816, 
-1.10911635110033, -0.999723362435733, -0.89337938721453, -0.766988745723311, 
-0.640949911207503, -0.557354889428034, -0.37862272938278, -0.228200809764493, 
-0.110527795707098, 0, 0.110527795707098, 0.228200809764493, 
0.37862272938278, 0.557354889428034, 0.640949911207503, 0.766988745723311, 
0.89337938721453, 0.999723362435733, 1.10911635110033, 1.22817675030816, 
1.36882733539455, 1.48669362532537, 1.6265976326061, 1.70946687980764, 
1.81862225736669, 2.19160406439047, 2.33308777876224, 2.51311768021067, 
2.5864505421683, 2.70167333082681, 2.83184663180451, 3.14956711773407, 
3.27884590260074, 3.34872310204811, 3.45665297878437, 3.68133161034538, 
3.77813524686729, 3.89501090892983, 4.01856478499323, 4.15153286112639, 
4.50152763272595, 4.69948913603343, 4.90747729878566, 5.10216264876024, 
5.30289294897202, 5.46484576488352, 5.74660855271358, 6.11711906602055, 
6.38157100998465, 6.64199852086489, 6.91751548158816, 7.66719491633901, 
8.0934438691888, 8.53401963497411, 8.89515033208928, 10.4384236674326, 
11.6420519179073, 13.3630613956461, 13.6245844768687, -13.7513240158161, 
-13.4949850845108, -11.6972632618919, -10.4696154936035, -8.96823049188587, 
-8.60864584793023, -8.16576044465774, -7.73344959477095, -6.97053016408726, 
-6.67565344738059, -6.41008219291174, -6.14910749861269, -5.78532336166338, 
-5.51109109533802, -5.34644256890291, -5.14116391069274, -4.94483810678764, 
-4.73911258917317, -4.53082008138683, -4.17869747763421, -4.05047164341461, 
-3.91581211159757, -3.79775240187192, -3.6964010627146, -3.47936581711638, 
-3.37242020290272, -3.30290438286576, -3.17462683337767, -2.85085507867997, 
-2.72420863226898, -2.60233967200701, -2.52948530961352, -2.34502396371101, 
-2.21085897720345, -1.84928001732781, -1.73668634525457, -1.65518019199163, 
-1.51336068884896, -1.39506478104353, -1.25112746056258, -1.1295492863675, 
-1.02018515280999, -0.904021410598258, -0.776556379825624, -0.640066072057238, 
-0.554047238235075, -0.376701966557133, -0.231463685042374, -0.110388540236378, 
0, 0.110388540236378, 0.231463685042374, 0.376701966557133, 0.554047238235075, 
0.640066072057238, 0.776556379825624, 0.904021410598258, 1.02018515280999, 
1.1295492863675, 1.25112746056258, 1.39506478104353, 1.51336068884896, 
1.65518019199163, 1.73668634525457, 1.84928001732781, 2.21085897720345, 
2.34502396371101, 2.52948530961352, 2.60233967200701, 2.72420863226898, 
2.85085507867997, 3.17462683337767, 3.30290438286576, 3.37242020290272, 
3.47936581711638, 3.6964010627146, 3.79775240187192, 3.91581211159757, 
4.05047164341461, 4.17869747763421, 4.53082008138683, 4.73911258917317, 
4.94483810678764, 5.14116391069274, 5.34644256890291, 5.51109109533802, 
5.78532336166338, 6.14910749861269, 6.41008219291174, 6.67565344738059, 
6.97053016408726, 7.73344959477095, 8.16576044465774, 8.60864584793023, 
8.96823049188587, 10.4696154936035, 11.6972632618919, 13.4949850845108, 
13.7513240158161, -13.5038153563633, -13.2373523390222, -11.5894414578226, 
-10.4087012189772, -8.82551281645418, -8.46290889731311, -8.02453396711809, 
-7.60406134878737, -6.86699820314081, -6.6099290032563, -6.3544029256183, 
-6.08663753750477, -5.70971751250438, -5.42077894932731, -5.26139485499848, 
-5.06499864973269, -4.87187647554418, -4.66173225584577, -4.47361508632088, 
-4.12564790942336, -3.98816098787005, -3.87518960476143, -3.75944221250401, 
-3.66697204643782, -3.43501009186589, -3.32614231903036, -3.2559207639547, 
-3.12568790968636, -2.81373363068119, -2.68019961742924, -2.57130991397796, 
-2.49752109350884, -2.32171388099973, -2.17325620779303, -1.78940871644707, 
-1.68352966297731, -1.59936153416788, -1.46128278798956, -1.34382587758861, 
-1.20630719708568, -1.08964596607244, -0.980225481600834, -0.88323868593752, 
-0.757871821632761, -0.641792114656659, -0.560506724513046, -0.380453009333927, 
-0.225091641300559, -0.110660491161603, 0, 0.110660491161603, 
0.225091641300559, 0.380453009333927, 0.560506724513046, 0.641792114656659, 
0.757871821632761, 0.88323868593752, 0.980225481600834, 1.08964596607244, 
1.20630719708568, 1.34382587758861, 1.46128278798956, 1.59936153416788, 
1.68352966297731, 1.78940871644707, 2.17325620779303, 2.32171388099973, 
2.49752109350884, 2.57130991397796, 2.68019961742924, 2.81373363068119, 
3.12568790968636, 3.2559207639547, 3.32614231903036, 3.43501009186589, 
3.66697204643782, 3.75944221250401, 3.87518960476143, 3.98816098787005, 
4.12564790942336, 4.47361508632088, 4.66173225584577, 4.87187647554418, 
5.06499864973269, 5.26139485499848, 5.42077894932731, 5.70971751250438, 
6.08663753750477, 6.3544029256183, 6.6099290032563, 6.86699820314081, 
7.60406134878737, 8.02453396711809, 8.46290889731311, 8.82551281645418, 
10.4087012189772, 11.5894414578226, 13.2373523390222, 13.5038153563633, 
-12.8877947524831, -12.5961340486959, -11.3210853809037, -10.2570925911286, 
-8.47030492676585, -8.10018637873416, -7.67303749757961, -7.28202887686486, 
-6.60931905266524, -6.44634841642492, -6.21582362929168, -5.93115698481963, 
-5.5215432443443, -5.19600239869575, -5.04972087076752, -4.87543206990054, 
-4.69028336184037, -4.46914150055587, -4.33123842894087, -3.99361363184664, 
-3.833076928421, -3.77408485453713, -3.6640925546724, -3.59372660759739, 
-3.32461379011727, -3.21096198541142, -3.13898393694403, -3.00388455382712, 
-2.72134261347931, -2.57066623804085, -2.49408041291093, -2.41796583370138, 
-2.26369776447253, -2.07966723692233, -1.64375650300888, -1.54786821816088, 
-1.46043531083332, -1.33166687876378, -1.21629813646533, -1.09475471308712, 
-0.990331188483095, -0.880770453063485, -0.831512873094893, -0.711368103958197, 
-0.64608803628934, -0.576583643383317, -0.389788923647592, -0.219325408944189, 
-0.101244293663156, 0, 0.101244293663156, 0.219325408944189, 
0.389788923647592, 0.576583643383317, 0.64608803628934, 0.711368103958197, 
0.831512873094893, 0.880770453063485, 0.990331188483095, 1.09475471308712, 
1.21629813646533, 1.33166687876378, 1.46043531083332, 1.54786821816088, 
1.64375650300888, 2.07966723692233, 2.26369776447253, 2.41796583370138, 
2.49408041291093, 2.57066623804085, 2.72134261347931, 3.00388455382712, 
3.13898393694403, 3.21096198541142, 3.32461379011727, 3.59372660759739, 
3.6640925546724, 3.77408485453713, 3.833076928421, 3.99361363184664, 
4.33123842894087, 4.46914150055587, 4.69028336184037, 4.87543206990054, 
5.04972087076752, 5.19600239869575, 5.5215432443443, 5.93115698481963, 
6.21582362929168, 6.44634841642492, 6.60931905266524, 7.28202887686486, 
7.67303749757961, 8.10018637873416, 8.47030492676585, 10.2570925911286, 
11.3210853809037, 12.5961340486959, 12.8877947524831, -12.6000848203634, 
-12.2966556390103, -11.1957507602953, -10.1862843945321, -8.30440651819497, 
-7.93147284818737, -7.50817793772083, -7.13162491301438, -6.48897104737938, 
-6.36994876479492, -6.15110072929745, -5.85854042138457, -5.43365721329602, 
-5.09102141962306, -4.95085939235108, -4.78689576531572, -4.60547103236952, 
-4.37919276705198, -4.26474198682156, -3.93194755639431, -3.77843705689023, 
-3.70907277842741, -3.61955988253518, -3.55951762156004, -3.27305364378077, 
-3.15716747633446, -3.08436906473098, -2.94699678899349, -2.67819176248474, 
-2.51950911610342, -2.45801068672049, -2.38080987129559, -2.23660157184075, 
-2.03595688651075, -1.58836441712333, -1.47187389747016, -1.39555037998287, 
-1.27113029247092, -1.15673682064109, -1.0426545765059, -0.943946623196274, 
-0.835837575946843, -0.805837349555374, -0.689648730659341, -0.648094429117022, 
-0.584092303333525, -0.394149224677363, -0.222824659020402, -0.0906541511144734, 
0, 0.0906541511144734, 0.222824659020402, 0.394149224677363, 
0.584092303333525, 0.648094429117022, 0.689648730659341, 0.805837349555374, 
0.835837575946843, 0.943946623196274, 1.0426545765059, 1.15673682064109, 
1.27113029247092, 1.39555037998287, 1.47187389747016, 1.58836441712333, 
2.03595688651075, 2.23660157184075, 2.38080987129559, 2.45801068672049, 
2.51950911610342, 2.67819176248474, 2.94699678899349, 3.08436906473098, 
3.15716747633446, 3.27305364378077, 3.55951762156004, 3.61955988253518, 
3.70907277842741, 3.77843705689023, 3.93194755639431, 4.26474198682156, 
4.37919276705198, 4.60547103236952, 4.78689576531572, 4.95085939235108, 
5.09102141962306, 5.43365721329602, 5.85854042138457, 6.15110072929745, 
6.36994876479492, 6.48897104737938, 7.13162491301438, 7.50817793772083, 
7.93147284818737, 8.30440651819497, 10.1862843945321, 11.1957507602953, 
12.2966556390103, 12.6000848203634, -12.7233949898779, -12.425009683628, 
-11.2494681735225, -10.2166322197219, -8.3755092456272, -8.00338523998922, 
-7.57923229725886, -7.19608684570266, -6.5405512372713, -6.40269304276938, 
-6.17884044516668, -5.8896632980985, -5.47132446137006, -5.13601542532135, 
-4.9932306291456, -4.82484171541241, -4.64182091659811, -4.41774407285591, 
-4.29324182862204, -3.95837714178017, -3.80090594237893, -3.73788575810611, 
-3.6386462286676, -3.57417931862452, -3.29515190899568, -3.18022337150066, 
-3.10777656095811, -2.97137842876953, -2.69668587115743, -2.54143464829308, 
-2.47346988209172, -2.39673461879726, -2.24821478269518, -2.05469079214647, 
-1.61210502089736, -1.50444445385474, -1.42335954097761, -1.29707578786137, 
-1.18226432293022, -1.06498427720905, -0.963826675880699, -0.85422851115692, 
-0.817708608597364, -0.698957479868998, -0.647234505242058, -0.580874151897233, 
-0.392280434624987, -0.221324908501217, -0.0951930012794266, 
0, 0.0951930012794266, 0.221324908501217, 0.392280434624987, 
0.580874151897233, 0.647234505242058, 0.698957479868998, 0.817708608597364, 
0.85422851115692, 0.963826675880699, 1.06498427720905, 1.18226432293022, 
1.29707578786137, 1.42335954097761, 1.50444445385474, 1.61210502089736, 
2.05469079214647, 2.24821478269518, 2.39673461879726, 2.47346988209172, 
2.54143464829308, 2.69668587115743, 2.97137842876953, 3.10777656095811, 
3.18022337150066, 3.29515190899568, 3.57417931862452, 3.6386462286676, 
3.73788575810611, 3.80090594237893, 3.95837714178017, 4.29324182862204, 
4.41774407285591, 4.64182091659811, 4.82484171541241, 4.9932306291456, 
5.13601542532135, 5.47132446137006, 5.8896632980985, 6.17884044516668, 
6.40269304276938, 6.5405512372713, 7.19608684570266, 7.57923229725886, 
8.00338523998922, 8.3755092456272, 10.2166322197219, 11.2494681735225, 
12.425009683628, 12.7233949898779, -12.9701665831908, -12.6818752140478, 
-11.3569688906404, -10.2773650952434, -8.51780191626772, -8.14868819459235, 
-7.72003821070641, -7.32508978114711, -6.64377488616525, -6.46822176338875, 
-6.23435390289731, -5.95194722735932, -5.54670516078474, -5.22605862710606, 
-5.07802507599128, -4.90078016073291, -4.71456527242172, -4.49489397213016, 
-4.35027647059818, -4.01126873151645, -3.85381415345849, -3.78760418054142, 
-3.67684233255883, -3.6035206970325, -3.33937554552141, -3.22636344257365, 
-3.15462026543263, -3.02017161524238, -2.73369677368098, -2.58531260689116, 
-2.50440723533775, -2.42860364735808, -2.27145544935968, -2.09218158273497, 
-1.66032132882236, -1.56891953844307, -1.47901197414181, -1.34899860381407, 
-1.23335063996306, -1.10967106859385, -1.00361116644947, -0.894069184830091, 
-0.838429443534018, -0.717586396553344, -0.645513602695347, -0.574433901587114, 
-0.388540562231589, -0.218323567844169, -0.104276269037671, 0, 
0.104276269037671, 0.218323567844169, 0.388540562231589, 0.574433901587114, 
0.645513602695347, 0.717586396553344, 0.838429443534018, 0.894069184830091, 
1.00361116644947, 1.10967106859385, 1.23335063996306, 1.34899860381407, 
1.47901197414181, 1.56891953844307, 1.66032132882236, 2.09218158273497, 
2.27145544935968, 2.42860364735808, 2.50440723533775, 2.58531260689116, 
2.73369677368098, 3.02017161524238, 3.15462026543263, 3.22636344257365, 
3.33937554552141, 3.6035206970325, 3.67684233255883, 3.78760418054142, 
3.85381415345849, 4.01126873151645, 4.35027647059818, 4.49489397213016, 
4.71456527242172, 4.90078016073291, 5.07802507599128, 5.22605862710606, 
5.54670516078474, 5.95194722735932, 6.23435390289731, 6.46822176338875, 
6.64377488616525, 7.32508978114711, 7.72003821070641, 8.14868819459235, 
8.51780191626772, 10.2773650952434, 11.3569688906404, 12.6818752140478, 
12.9701665831908), .Dim = c(99L, 11L))
```

Em cada coluna eu quero integrar usando a função `integrate` do R, e colocar o valor dessa integral na matriz `integrais`. O problema que eu encontro é o erro:

```
Error in integrate(integrando.funcao.t, lower = 0.01, upper = 0.5, subdivisions = 1000) : 
  extremely bad integrand behaviour

integrais=matrix(0,11)

for (t in 1:11){


integrando.funcao.t = approxfun(thau,funcao[,t],rule=2)

integrais[t,1]=integrate(integrando.funcao.t, lower = 0.01, upper = 0.5,subdivisions = 1000)$value

}
```

Há como contornar esse problema com a mesma função `integrate`? Ou vou precisar aproximar de maneira não linear? Se for esse o caso como faço?

Obrigado

Answer (score 3):

A função `integrate` não serve para calcular integrais desta maneira. Para usar especificamente esta função, tu precisa escrever a função a ser integrada no `R`. No teu caso, como os valores da função já estão calculados, o que tu deve fazer é usar algo como a Fórmula de Simpson, como é mostrado [nesta resposta aqui mesmo no StackOverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/161621/49033).

Eu plotei o conteúdo do objeto `funcao` e obtive o seguinte:

```
matplot(funcao, type="l", col="black", lty=1)
```

[image: grafico]

Dado o teu histórico de perguntas por aqui, estas 11 funções tem cada de funções quartil da distribuição normal. Ignore os números do eixo x deste gráfico, pois eles estão mostrando apenas a posição dos valores dentro do data frame e, por isso, variam entre 1 e 99. Olhando esta figura, eu diria que as integrais são todas iguais a zero. Para testar isto, assumi duas hipóteses que não estão explícitas na tua pergunta original:

1. O passo entre cada linha do objeto `funcao` é constante, isto é, a função em questão foi calculada em pontos equidistantes
2. Como estou desconfiado que é uma função quantil, ela não deveria ser calculada entre 0,01 e 0,50, mas sim entre 0,01 e 0,99

Minha resposta se baseia nestas duas hipóteses e posso estar enganado. Caso eu esteja, por favor, me corrija.

```
# pacote para calcular as integrais pela Fórmula de Simpson
library(Bolstad) 

# vetor variando entre 0,01 e 0,99, com tamanho igual ao numero
# de linhas da matriz funcao
x <- seq(from=0.01, to=0.99, length.out=dim(funcao)[1])

# inicializa o vetor para guardar os resultados das integracoes
integrais <- 0

# loop para calcular um numero de integrais igual ao numero de 
# colunas da matriz funcao
# utilizo j como contador porque t eh uma funcao do R e nao eh
# interessante utilizar palavras reservadas da linguagem
# como nome de objetos
for (j in 1:dim(funcao)[2]){
    integrais[j] <- sintegral(x, funcao[, j])$value
}

# resultado
integrais
 [1] -5.149960e-16 -5.657367e-16 -5.128276e-16 -4.902762e-16
 [5] -5.373306e-16 -5.893723e-16 -5.306085e-16 -5.205255e-16
 [9] -5.434021e-16 -5.186823e-16 -5.606409e-16
```

Como eu desconfiava, todas as integrais ficaram iguais a zero.

Uma observação importante a ser feita é a respeito da divergência desta função. Ela não está definida em 0 e 1. Portanto, se te interessar calcular a integral entre 0,01 e 0,50, tu vai obter um valor. Se calcular entre 0,001 e 0,500, tu vai obter um valor ainda maior. Se calcular entre 0,0001 e 0,5000, vai obter um valor maior ainda. Quanto mais a função se aproximar dos seus limites em 0 e 1, mais ela vai divergir.